Как можно распознать маленькую деталь на большом изображении?
Есть фотография загона скота на животноводческой ферме.
Вот пример фотографии с коровами.

На шее каждой коровы висит яркий LED-фонарик. В какой-то момент он загорается, остальное время он не горит.
Задача заключается в том, чтобы иметь возможность определять где [координаты] на снимке находится горящий LED-фонарик.
Я пробовал:

обучить детекторную нейросеть (типа YoloV9) на датасете, с горящими LED-фонариками. Но точность распознавания получается слишком низка из-за маленького размера (несколько пикселей) горящей точки, чтобы нейросеть смогла научиться обобщать такие изображения (фактически, чем горящий фонарик отличается от просто белого пятна на шкуре коровы?)
Применить к фотографиям загона фильтры. У меня была гипотеза, что поскольку горящий фонарик ярче, чем весь окружающий фон, преобразовать изображение в градации серого и сделать порог "прохождения" для пикселей, например 240. Т.е. все пиксели, которые темнее чем 240 - сбрасываются в 0, а те, которые ярче 240 - устанавливаются в 255.
Вот тот же снимок, обработанный таким образом:

видно, что LED-фонарик сброшен в ноль, при этом спина этой же коровы - оказалась светлее LED-фонарика.

Коллеги, может кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей или просто выскажите идею возможных путей решения этой задачи.

Отследить включение - в одном кадре фонарик не горит, в следующем смещения малы, а положительная разность яркостей велика (если АРУ отработает, то у остального кадра будет небольшое снижение яркости)

дело в том, что фонарик может загореться на любой корове и корова может находиться в любом месте кадра

Это понятно. Но разность соседних кадров будет содержать тонкие контуры - сдвиг очертаний предметов, и солидного размера пятно - где загорелся фонарик.

Тогда попробуйте подобрать порог, при котором фонарик ещё виден и имеет некую характерную форму, по которой его и сможет отделить нейросеть от снега, например. Я бы попробовал на вашем месте поиграться в графическом редакторе с яркостью, контрастностью и прочим что там бывает. Полностью отсеять другие яркие объекты вы не сможете, да это и не нужно. Нужно сделать так, чтобы 1) фонарик был виден 2) свет его имел форму, отличимую от других объектов. А дальше уже нейросеть как-то обучить искать именно эту форму. Но вообще результат сложно гарантировать, задача непростая.


имеет некую характерную форму, по которой его и сможет отделить нейросеть от снега,

CrazyElf: да, эта идея первой пришла мне в голову, если бы фонарик можно было по каким-то критериям однозначно отделить от окружающего фона....  например фонарик светил бы красным/зеленым светом и был бы в форме звезды (как вариант) - такая задача думаю легко решилась бы детекторными нейросетями,  но задача в том и заключается, что он белый и это точка/пятно на изображении

MBo: извините, не очень хорошо Вас понял

разность соседних кадров будет содержать тонкие контуры - сдвиг очертаний предметов, и >солидного размера пятно - где загорелся фонарик

на картинке много белых пятен (после применения любых фильтров) и большинство из них ярче и больше по размеру, чем фонарик...   как в таких условиях получить заметную разность яркостей?

@Yustas А вы таки попробуйте поиграться яркостями-контрастностями. Я тоже на досуге попробую, как время будет. Мне кажется там можно добиться того, что будет что-то круглое звездатое, что легче будет отделить от других объектов. Когда найдёте способ, можно будет придумать, как это автоматизировать через cv2, например. P.S. Только сейчас понял, что это не снег на стекле, а прям коровы, вид сверху ))

И разными цветовыми каналами я бы тоже попробовал поиграться. В общем, всем, что позволяет графический редактор. И фильтрами. В cv2 фильтры тоже есть, можно потом автоматом будет фильтровать нужным образом.

@CrazyElf:  спасибо за советы, попробую

@Yustas Смысл в обработке не единичных кадров, а именно разности двух соседних кадров. Где было белое - белое и останется, а разность кадров будет чёрной. Если фонарик был серым, а стал белым - в разности будет белое пятно.
